# Pattern matching using regex in python not giving expected op

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i have sentence and need below pattern to be detected and substring till the end of that pattern

```
subtask = 'Subtask25-35-23-860-05000-002TOPEND-UDYDATE20160901'
dd = re.findall('\-[0-9]*',subtask)
ind = subtask.index(dd[-1]) + len(dd[-1])
subtask [:ind]
```

expected output is: 'Subtask25-35-23-860-05000-002'.
dd o/p: ['-35', '-23', '-860', '-05000', '-002', '-']
expected is: ['-35', '-23', '-860', '-05000']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boundaries `\b`

**Ex:**

```
import re

subtask = 'Subtask25-35-23-860-05000-002TOPEND-UDYDATE20160901'
print(re.findall(r"\b(-\d+)\b", subtask))
```

**Output:**

```
['-35', '-23', '-860', '-05000']
```

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, How to identify 25-35-23-860-05000-002 this pattern ? and finally i need output as "Subtask 25-35-23-860-05000-002".